# Obtener contenido especifico en un JSON

Tags: php, html, json, url

Necesito capturar el `uid` y el `osgjsSize` que están dentro de `Files`. No sé cómo resolver este error (*soy un estudiante / novato*). Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

```
<?php $url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/ZivzYNvM';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($json as $uid) {
echo "<td>".$uid['files'][0]['uid']."</td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo origen de pastebin que  muestras sólo tiene una entrada que contiene una llave `files`, cuyo contenido es:

```
"files": [

    {

        "uid": "6a525a5d9ec1452086427929bf0890ae",
        "flag": 0,
        "osgjsSize": 59831,
        "wireframeSize": 72052,
        "modelSize": 161452,
        "osgjsUrl": "https://media.sketchfab.com/urls/418eacc1eefe446591aff5738b79d595/dist/models/6a525a5d9ec1452086427929bf0890ae/file.osgjs.gz"

    }

],
```

A falta de mayor información, da la impresión de que lo que obtienes al hacer:

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
```

Es un array asociativo donde casa llave es del tipo

```
/i/models/<uid>[/<otro string]
```

Esas llaves tienen como valor un array asociativo en donde uno de sus elementos *puede* ser `files`

Si el elemento `files` existe, entonces aparentemente tiene la forma de un array de uno o más arrays asociativos con las llaves que necesitas, `uid` y `osgsize`.

---

Como tu pastebin tiene un solo elemento, y la idea es dar una solución general, pensemos en cambio que el origen de tu archivo es https://pastebin.com/raw/dhU1Q97J, que tiene varias entradas con la propiedad files, e incluso una de ellas contiene dos archivos.

Mi planteamiento sería:

Primero: obtienes el array asociativo completo

```
$url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/dhU1Q97J'; // ojo que este es mi pastebin, no el original
$data      = file_get_contents($url);
$json      = json_decode($data, true);
```

Filtras aquellas entradas que tengan un elemento `files`

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($json, function ($element) {
    return isset($element['files']);
});
```

De entre éstas, sólo te interesa la llave `files` y no el resto de las propiedades, así que mapeas lo filtrado para quedarte sólo con `files`

```
$mapped_array = array_map(function ($element) {
    return $element['files'];
}, $filtered_array);
```

En este punto `$mapped_array` es un arreglo de 0 a N elementos, cada uno de los cuales es el elemento `files` de una de las entradas de tu array original, y por lo tanto es array de 0 a N files.

Ese arreglo puedes imprimirlo como:

```
foreach ($mapped_array as $files) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $file['uid'] . '</td><td>' . $file['osgjsSize'] . '</td></tr>';
        }

    }
```

Para que quede un poco más bonito, envolví todo en una comprobación para imprimir la tabla sólo si hay files para mostrar:

```
<?php
$url  = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/dhU1Q97J';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data, true);

$filtered_array = array_filter($json, function ($element) {
    return isset($element['files']);
});

$mapped_array = array_map(function ($element) {
    return $element['files'];
}, $filtered_array);

if (sizeof($mapped_array) > 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Uid</th><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;osgjsSize</th></tr>';

    foreach ($mapped_array as $files) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $file['uid'] . '</td><td style="text-align:right">' . $file['osgjsSize'] . '</td></tr>';
        }

    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

El resultado puedes verlo aquí:

https://examples.ffflabs.com/osg.php

Comment: Amigo, créame que si estuviera en este momento frente a usted le diera un abrazo y le brindaría algo de beber y comer. Quedo eternamente agradecido con usted, excelente ejemplo. Saludos cordiales.